# Making a executable for my python gui application

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

im having this problem, i made a fully functional tkinter aplication and made an exe with cx_freeze... my problem is that i didnt use OOP(Object Oriented Programming) to make my app and when i run my program.exe file it doesnt open my GUI...

any tips?

for the record my app code starts something like this

```
from tkinter import *
frame = Frame()
f.pack()
```

i didnt use a class to create my app or another class to make my db connection..

thanks for your answer

EDIT: here is the complete code:
https://www.dropbox.com/l/HscgvyINCe85SLwmMTwVAp?

This is for a database class, it works i got a 100, im just trying to learn how to make an exe... maybe its the way my program is made the problem of why it doesnt show in my compiled exe, it works on python shell btw

Comment: You program does not show the GUI. Try to add `mainloop()` at the end. But this does not seem to be your original code at all, since it does not even compile. Does it show a gui when you just run it in python? `python your_Script.py`

Comment: let me try that... i also dont have an __init__ so my app only works when i run it on python shell

Comment: it doesnt show anything... it just shows me an error like this:SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file C:\Users\Abdul Hamid\Desktop\Pro
yecto Final Bases de datos\proyectofinalbd.py on line 870, but no encoding decla
red; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: Maybe you should post a code snipped that lets us reproduce your problem and then ask a question how to fix the first bug you encounter, instead of how to wrap that in an exe file.

Comment: ok ill add the code, i tried but its really too long, anyway my program works prefectly with python shell but not with my exe... let me add the code

Comment: When you run the exe, does it show any error? I mean, run it from command line, not by double-clicking.

Comment: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file C:\Users\Abdul Hamid\Desktop\Pro yecto Final Bases de datos\proyectofinalbd.py on line 870, but no encoding decla red; see python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: ok i corrected that error, now it says nothing, it doesent even shows anything now x_X